# Keys into columns and values into rows in a Map

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataframe in input with an id column and a Map column.

The Map:

```
key1 -> value1, key2 -> value2 ... key100 -> value100,
key1 -> value3, key2 -> value4 ... key100 -> value200
```

I want in output this result:

```
id   key1     key2    ...  key100
1    value1   value2       value100
2    value3   value4       value200
```

Thanks for your returns and have a nice day.

Comment: If all the keys are the same accross your dataframe, you should consider having a Struct instead of a Map. Then, you can simply use `select id, s.* from df` to achieve your desired result.

Comment: Do you know the keys a priori. If you don´t, do all rows have the same type and same number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution based on Spark build-in functions:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{monotonically_increasing_id, explode, first}

val df = Seq(
    (Map("key1" -> "value1", "key2" -> "value2", "key3" -> "value3", "key4" -> "value4")),
    (Map("key1" -> "value1", "key2" -> "value2")),
    (Map("key1" -> "value1", "key3" -> "value3")))
.toDF("map_data")

df.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id)
  .select($"id", explode($"map_data"))
  .groupBy("id")
  .pivot("key")
  .agg(first("value"))
  .show(false)

// +---+------+------+------+------+
// |id |key1  |key2  |key3  |key4  |
// +---+------+------+------+------+
// |0  |value1|value2|value3|value4|
// |1  |value1|value2|null  |null  |
// |2  |value1|null  |value3|null  |
// +---+------+------+------+------+
```

### Explanation

1. `withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id)` : add a unique id for each row.
2. `explode($"map_data")` : Explode `map_data` this will create two additional columns, `key` and `value`.
3. `groupBy...pivot` : Group by id and pivot on keys